# Wald Martingale for Lévy Processes

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, levy-processes

in the book "ruin probabilities" by Asmussen and Albrecher, in Chapter II Thm. 1.2, the following statement is made:

*Let $\{X_t\}$ be a Lévy process and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. If $\mathbb{E}[e^{\alpha X_t}]$ is finite for all $t>0$, then it holds $\mathbb{E}[e^{\alpha X_t}]=e^{t\kappa(\alpha)}$ for some $\kappa(\alpha)\in\mathbb{R}$ and the process $e^{\alpha X_t-t\kappa(\alpha)}$ is a martingale.*

In the proof they mention you have to choose $\kappa(\alpha)=\log\mathbb{E}[e^{\alpha(X_1-X_0)}]$.

Now I get, why the mentioned process is a martingale, but I somehow do not see, why $\mathbb{E}[e^{\alpha X_t}]=e^{t\kappa(\alpha)}$ should hold for that specific choice of $\kappa$. I mean for $t\in\mathbb{N}$ it's easy, but what about a general $t\in\mathbb{R}$?

Any hints are much appreciated!

Comment: There is something odd about the initial condition, e.g. if, say $X_0=1$ and $t=0$ then $\mathbb{E}e^{\alpha X_t} \neq e^{t \kappa(\alpha)}$. Either you have to assume $X_0 =0$ or you need to replace $X_t$ by $X_t-X_0$.

Comment: yeah I think so too. From the context, I'd assume it should read $X_t-X_0$. But still, how does the argument go for arbitrary $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\alpha>0$. Define for all $y\geq0$:
$$ f(y)=E[e^{\alpha (X_y-X_0)}]$$
Then from Lévy properties we can prove:

Property 1:
$$ f(yn)=f(y)^n \quad \forall y\geq0,n\in\{1,2,3,...\}$$

From Property 1 alone we can prove:

Property 2:
$$f(y/m)=f(y)^{1/m} \quad \forall y\geq0,m\in \{1,2,3,...\}$$

Now from Properties 1 and 2 we get for any rational number $n/m>0$ (for $n,m$ positive integers):
$$ f(n/m)=f(1)^{n/m}$$
However properties of Lévy imply $f$ is continuous and so for any $y\geq0$ we can approximate $y$ with rational numbers to conclude
$$f(y)=f(1)^y$$

Comment: As in the saz comment, if $X_0=0$ then $f(y)=E[e^{\alpha X_y}]$, which gives the book result.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly the answer I was looking for!

Comment: Do you have an elementary proof that $f$ is continuous? ("elementary" = without using deep results on Lévy processes)

Comment: @saz : That question is hard.  In my above answer I really  just assumed $f$ was continuous.  It suffices to prove $f$ is right-continuous at $0$.  After some effort, I can prove it if either (i) $X_t\geq 0$ with probability 1 for all $t\geq 0$; (ii) $E[\sup_{t \in [0,1]} e^{\alpha X_t}]<\infty$. I don't know how to prove it in general.  However define $h(x)=\log(f(x))$ we get $h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)$ and it is known that such functions $h$ are either continuous at $x=0$, or unbounded on a sequence of positive numers $x_i$ that approach 0.

Comment: I posted a related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269965/are-nonnegative-levy-proceesses-almost-always-nondecreasing

Comment: @Michael I also thought about it for a while without finding a nice proof. Under certain additional assumptions (e.g. $E(\sup_{t \in [0,1]} e^{\alpha X_t})<\infty$ or $E(e^{\beta X_t})< \infty$ for some $\beta>\alpha$) it's relatively simple, but the general case is tricky.

Comment: @saz : In your second case, do you really mean $E[e^{\beta X_t}]\leq c$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ for some $c<\infty$ and some $\beta > \alpha$?  The weaker case $E[e^{\beta X_t}]<\infty$ for some $\beta>\alpha$ is not obvious to me.